# Slow page serving on ASP.NET MVC 4 web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm experiencing a very slow random response from some of the pages of my web site.
My page usually takes 1 second to load, but in some cases, unpredictably, it can take 10 seconds or even worse.

Find here a screenshot of the MiniProfiler output:

[image: Example of very slow served page]

As you can see from the output, there's something in the stack of ASP.NET that is stuck, while the actual code is fast enough.

This slowness happens sometimes, even during my normal navigation of the pages (not only on this page). On my local machine everything is always pretty fast, while both on production and staging servers (which are configured exactly in the same way) the same problem happens.

I think I'm doing something wrong in the configuration of the server or of the web app. Or maybe I'm using some internal ASP.NET object (like the session) in a wrong way.

Could you help me by providing any hint that can drive me to the correct solution?

Thank you

cghersi

Comment: Is it happening when multiple users are accessing or replicable for a single user also?

Comment: replicable for a single user also

Comment: Are you using bundling, like @Styles.Render("~/Content/MyStyle.css") or something similar?

Comment: some examples can be <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/prettify/prettify.css")" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> or @Html.Partial("_CommonJavascript")

Answer (score 0):

Though this might not be an answer but big for comment, so writing here... At the moment I can think of following checks:

1) Verify once the bundling and minification is done and those minified versions are rendering to browser.

2) If some pages are slow, you can check what is the logic in those action methods. How expensive the database/service queries called from those action methods.

3) Deploy instrumentation/logging in those actions and see what is the duration spent inside those actions.

Comment: Thank you Siva, after instrumenting ( a lot ) the code, I was able to find that the main culprit seems to be the method View() in the controller action to return the actual cshtml page (I'm using Razor). Moreover, it is some internal ASP.NET mechanism between the invocation of View() method and the beginning of the code inside the CSHTML page that I need to serve. Any clue on this?

Comment: That sounds strange. Did you try with providing view path and name without extension (cshtml/vbhtml). Check in the layout page any potential code that can delay, like cusom helpers/logic etc. Did you implemented any custom filters? Other than these I could not think beyond, this moment!!

Comment: Also check if you lazy load any entity framework/orm data. If yes try projectig them to appropriate object/List/array before calling view.